# Upload file using multipart/form-data to aws s3 returns RequestTimeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, post, amazon-s3, timeout

I'm trying to upload a file using multipart/form-data POST request.
The same request works for others on different systems, but not for my PC.
I get "RequestTimeout, Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed" error from the s3 server.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and curl for sending the request.
Also tried the --data-binary option for curl with the same results.

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data, boundary=xxxxxxxxxx" --data @x.txt http://some-server.s3.amazonaws.com
```

x.txt looks like this:

```
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

someaccesskey
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

200
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

/somedir/somefilename.png
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Cache-Control"

no-cache
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/png
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

somepolicy==
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

somesignature=
--xxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="somefilename.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

S
--xxxxxxxxxx--
```

Answer (score 0):

After viewing the exiting packets from my machine in Wireshark I've found that Windows reduces the length of a packet that it tries to send to Amazon, Ubuntu left it as the MTU 1500, after manualy changing it to 536, the packet got through.