# Error while uploading image on AWS S3 - with Axios & React-Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, mobile, axios

I'm trying to upload an image from my Mobile App (with React-Native) on AWS S3 with a presigned URL. I'm using axios to send the request.
The problem is that even if my image is uploaded on AWS, if I download it and try to open it says it's corrupted. I tried to open with Photoshop and it works :/

Creating the formData:

```
const createFormData = (photo) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', {
        name: photo.fileName, // a name
        type: photo.type, // image/jpg
        uri: photo.uri, // the uri starting with file://....
    });

    return data;
};
```

My PUT request:

```
const formData = createFormData(responseImage)
axios({
method: "put",
   url: awsURL.data.url_thumbnail,
   data: formData,
   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how it works.

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
```

The content-type *multipart/form-data* also contains a field called *boundary* separated by a delimiter. You can get more details [here](https://golangbyexample.com/multipart-form-data-content-type-golang/). The article has the details for the format of boundary.

Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282491/upload-file-using-multipart-form-data-to-aws-s3-returns-requesttimeout) for the same.

Hope it helps!

PS: There are some articles related to parsing data for multipart/form-data that I can't find right now, which explain how to parse the data before uploading so that the data isn't corrupted.

Comment: Tried to add a boundary but still nothing. I  tried to open the corrupted image using a text editor I've noticed that at the beginning there was the boundary (not the one I added!) along with content-disposition and content-type. I removed it and the image is not corrupted any longer. But why this? How can I solve without having to edit the file manually?